# How to access tasks parameters from an Ansible task in the Python module code?

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

Is it possible to access Ansible tasks parameters from the Python module code?

Specifically, I would like to check if there is a `register` on the task in order to return a more complete info set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is it possible to access tasks parameters from the Python code of an Ansible module?*

Yes, of course. You may have a look into [Developing modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html) and [Creating a module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#creating-a-module), in example

```py
def run_module():
    # define available arguments/parameters a user can pass to the module
    module_args = dict(
        name=dict(type='str', required=True),
        new=dict(type='bool', required=False, default=False)
    )
```

> *Specifically, I would like to check if there is a register on the task*

Please take note that [Registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) of the [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html) is done

> *... from the output of an Ansible task with the task keyword `register`.*

This means the task, respective the module called within doesn't know about the fact if the output will become registered or not and since that is done after the execution of the module code and providing the final result.

> *... in order to return a more complete info set.*

Therefore you need to provide an other way of controlling the data structure of the result set.

In example

```py
...
        supports_check_mode=True
...
    if module.check_mode:
...
```

Or just introduce a separate parameter on your Custom Module like

```yaml
verbose: True
```

or

```yaml
verbose_level: 1 # whereby 0 means false or OFF and i.e. up to 4
```

which can be checked within the module and simply controls the verbosity of the result set.